# Unity Animator State Parameter not Changing Properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am having an issue where the animator is changing the State parameter to 3 for some reason whenever I move to the right. I keep checking my code and I'm not sure why this is happening. It was working fine previously and the only thing that I changed was that I switched out the sprite I was using originally.

Here are things I've done so far to try and solve the issue:

1. I also made sure to adjust my collider to match the new sprites size as well.
2. I have a parameter called "State" in my Animator and have used debug.log to try and figure out if there is a section of my code in UpdateAnimationState() which is causing it to bug out, however after each one it shows that I'm switching to the correct state, but it very quickly updates the State to 3 (jumping).
   This seems to only happen when I move to the right, but at one point it happened when I was moving to the left. I'm not sure how this changed to moving to the right but now it's only doing it in that direction.
3. I tried remaking the entire object again just in case the issue occurred when I swapped the sprite, however it's still happening on the new object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if anyone is free Saturday, I can share my screen via discord to show the actual project and any settings I have setup, the hierachy, animator settings, etc. Or if it's easier, I can share the project files via github.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

// "RequireComponent" ensures that the rigidbody component exists on the current gameObject and the Rigidbody cannot be removed before the PlayerMovement script is removed.
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Primary Variables
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    public AudioSource jumpSFX;
    

    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7.1f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpStrength = 11f;
    [SerializeField] private float fallSpeed = 4f;

    private float raycastDistance = 0.2f;
    private float startingSpeed = 0f;
    private float horizontal;
    private bool facingRight = true;
    private bool doubleJump;
    private float coyoteTime = 0.15f;
    private float coyoteTimeCounter;
    private float airborneSpeedReduction = 1.4f;
    private float acceleration = 19.5f;
    #endregion

    private enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling }

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        // Reduces movespeed while in the air
        if (!Grounded())
        {
            jumpingMoveSpeed(); 
        }

        // Applies coyote time
        if (Grounded())
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;            
        }
        else
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Flips the character based on the move direction
        if (!facingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (facingRight && horizontal < 0f)
        {
            Flip();
        }

        // Raycast down to check if the player is grounded
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheck.position, Vector2.down, raycastDistance, groundLayer))
        {
            doubleJump = true;
        }
        SmoothMovement();
        UpdateAnimationState();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Allows the character to continue moving forward when jumping
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * startingSpeed, rb.velocity.y);


        // Increases gravity when the character reaches the peak of their jump
        if (rb.velocity.y < 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (fallSpeed - 1f) * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // This gradually increases moveSpeed when moving instead of starting at the max moveSpeed.

    }

    private void SmoothMovement()
    {
        // Smooths out the movement so that the character doesn't start at max speed.
        // Instead it starts from 0 then goes up to the moveSpeed value.
        if (horizontal == 0)
        {
            startingSpeed = 0;
        }
        if(horizontal != 0 && Grounded())
        {
            if (startingSpeed < moveSpeed)
            {
                startingSpeed += acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
                if (startingSpeed > moveSpeed)
                {
                    startingSpeed = moveSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Movement Methods
    public void Move(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        horizontal = context.ReadValue<Vector2>().x;
    }

    public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.performed) // Remove coyoteTimeCounter > 0 if this doesn't work
        {
            if (coyoteTimeCounter > 0) // This used to say Grounded() but has been changed to coyoteTime > 0. Remove this note once testing is done.
            {
                jumpingMoveSpeed();
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpStrength);
                doubleJump = true;
                jumpSFX.Play();
            }
            else if (doubleJump)
            {
                jumpingMoveSpeed();
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpStrength);
                doubleJump = false;
                coyoteTimeCounter = 0f;
                jumpSFX.Play();
            }
        }
        else if (context.canceled)
        {
            if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 localeScale = transform.localScale;
        localeScale.x *= -1f;
        transform.localScale = localeScale;
    }

    private bool Grounded()
    {
        // Check if the player is grounded using raycasting
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheck.position, Vector2.down, raycastDistance, groundLayer);
        return hit.collider != null;
    }

    private void jumpingMoveSpeed()
    {
        startingSpeed = moveSpeed;
        startingSpeed = startingSpeed / airborneSpeedReduction;
    }

    private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        if (horizontal > 0 || horizontal < 0)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }

        anim.SetInteger("State", (int)state);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to define an int value for your MovementState enum. Something like this: private enum MovementState { idle = 0, running = 1, jumping = 2, falling = 3 }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing the value of the fall check to negative.

```
private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        if (horizontal > 0 || horizontal < 0)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > 0.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -0.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }

        anim.SetInteger("State", (int)state);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people